# Can we discourage the use of the [ios] on Swift/Metal/Objective-C/etc questions that are not iOS-specific?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I notice that many users are rote tagging questions about the Swift language as [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) for some reason. Maybe they happen to be asking the question because they are creating an iOS app in Swift even though the answer would be no different if they were making a macOS app, or something else.

Even if Swift is predominantly used for iOS apps (and also macOS apps too), I do not see the benefit having platform-agnostic Swift questions be arbitrarily tagged as [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). If the question and answers would not be any different on any platform/does not involve any iOS-specific functionality, I think this tag should not be used.

So how can we discourage misusing the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag? Can a user edit the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) excerpt to emphasis the fact that the tag is for iOS-specific questions and not for questions that involve technologies commonly used on iOS, but that are not specific to iOS?

Comment: Is it possible there's a significant number of swift devs working solely with iOS that can't tell when a given problem isn't specific to iOS? not using irrelevant tags on your question is a general rule, not specific to swift or ios. The [swift excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info) could certainly be modified, but it already seems to pretty clearly state how it and related tags should be used.

Comment: @KevinB I still would expect it to be relatively easy to use some rule of thumb. Like if it involves UIKit, it's iOS. If it involves any iPhone or iPad specific features, it's iOS. If it involves core language features that are part of Foundation, it's probably not.

Comment: @KevinB Probably inexperience. Mobile development is often a first stop for many newcomers to programming. So either they’re new to programming, to Stack Overflow, or to both.

Comment: So, again, the solution is probably better onboarding, and guidance and help to new users, but that train has left. No point in begging any more for it.